# Python Trouble for ESPN FF

Tags: python

First time posting here, but having trouble with some code that I'm using to pull fantasy football data from ESPN. I pulled this from Steven Morse's blog (https://stmorse.github.io/journal/espn-fantasy-v3.html) and it appears to work EXCEPT for one error that I'm getting. The error is:

```
File "<ipython-input-65-56a5896c1c3c>", line 3, in <listcomp>
    game['away']['teamId'], game['away']['totalPoints'],

KeyError: 'away'
```

I've looked in the dictionary and found that 'away' is in there. What I can't figure out is why 'home' works but not 'away'. Here is the code I'm using. Any help is appreciated:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/ffl/seasons/2020/segments/0/leagues/721579?view=mMatchupScore'
      
r = requests.get(url,
                 cookies={"swid": "{1E653FDE-DA4A-4CC6-A53F-DEDA4A6CC663}",
                          "espn_s2": "AECpfE9Zsvwwsl7N%2BRt%2BAPhSAKmSs%2F2ZmQVuHJeKG8LGgLBDfRl0j88CvzRFsrRjLmjzASAdIUA9CyKpQJYBfn6avgXoPHJgDiCqfDPspruYqHNENjoeGuGfVqtPewVJGv3rBJPFMp1ugWiqlEzKiT9IXTFAIx3V%2Fp2GBuYjid2N%2FFcSUlRlr9idIL66tz2UevuH4F%2FP6ytdM7ABRCTEnrGXoqvbBPCVbtt6%2Fu69uBs6ut08ApLRQc4mffSYCONOqW1BKbAMPPMbwgCn1d5Ruubl"})


d = r.json()

df = [[
        game['matchupPeriodId'],
        game['away']['teamId'], game['away']['totalPoints'],
        game['home']['teamId'], game['home']['totalPoints']
        
    ] for game in d['schedule']]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Week', 'Team1', 'Score1', 'Team2', 'Score2'])
df['Type'] = ['Regular' if w<=14 else 'Playoff' for w in df['Week']]
```

Comment: If you want help, you have to include the actual data you are working with. This code will break on any tiny deviation in the input data from what you expect.

Maybe it's easer to make a dataframe first `pd.DataFrame(d['schedule'])` and then use pandas to reshape the data into the shape you want. Pandas dataframes are suitable for real world data which often have some values missing.

Comment: OK. I edited the code to include the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like some of the games in the schedule don't have an away team:

```
{'home': {'adjustment': 0.0,
  'cumulativeScore': {'losses': 0, 'statBySlot': None, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 0},
  'pointsByScoringPeriod': {'14': 102.7},
  'teamId': 1,
  'tiebreak': 0.0,
  'totalPoints': 102.7},
 'id': 78,
 'matchupPeriodId': 14,
 'playoffTierType': 'WINNERS_BRACKET',
 'winner': 'UNDECIDED'}
```

For nested json data like this, it's often easier to use `pandas.json_normalize` which flattens the data structure and gives you a data frame with lots of columns with names like `home.cumulativeScore.losses` etc.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['schedule'])
```

Then you can reshape the dataframe by dropping columns you don't care about and so on.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['schedule'])

column_names = {
    'matchupPeriodId':'Week', 
    'away.teamId':'Team1', 
    'away.totalPoints':'Score1',
    'home.teamId':'Team2', 
    'home.totalPoints':'Score2',
}

df = df.reindex(columns=column_names).rename(columns=column_names)
df['Type'] = ['Regular' if w<=14 else 'Playoff' for w in df['Week']]
```

For the games where there's no away team, pandas will populate those columns with NaN values.

```
df[df.Team1.isna()]
```

[image]